# having trouble reading chars in C

Tags: c, char

So i've got this program where i read 5 numbers and a comma as chars, and represent them all together. I've managed to do so, but the output is super strange..

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

int i=0;
float number = 0.0;
    char f;



printf("Introduce a number in the following format (ccc,cc):\n");

for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
    f=getchar();


    if(f=='\n' && i<6){
        printf("the number is not correct.\n");
        exit(1); }
    if(i==4 && f!=','){
        printf("The number doesn't have a comma.\n");
        exit(1); }
    if(i==4)
        continue;
    if((f<'0') || (f>'9')){
        printf(" %d is not a number .\n", i);
        exit(1); }



        switch (i)
        {
            case 1 : number = (f*100);
                break;
            case 2 : number += (f*10);
                break;
            case 3 : number = number + f;
                break;
            case 4: ;
                break;
            case 5 : number += (f * 0.1);
                break;
            case 6 : number += (f*0.01);
                break;
        }



}
    printf("The number you inserted is :%f\n",number);
}
```

The output with the number 123,45 is supposed to be exactly the same number, but instead of that i get a super awkward thing :

```
Introduce a number in the following format (ccc,cc):  

123,45  

The number you inserted is :5456.729980
```

any help guys ?

Answer (score 1):

`f` contains code of character, not a numerical value of a digit (e.g. code of '0' is 48, not zero), that's why you get 'strange' output.

You have to translate `f` from digit (character) to its numerical value: use `f - '0'` instead of `f` in your calculations (inside `switch`). Or just put `f = f - '0';` before the `switch`.

`f - '0'` is a valid conversion: all character codes for digits go in sequence from '0' to '9' (it's easy to see if you look at ASCII table). So if `f` contains `'0'`, `f - '0'` is `0` (note: a number, not a character), if `f` is `'1'`, `f - '0'` is `'1' - '0'` == `1`, etc.

Comment: i changed every f in the switch statement, and got this output : The number you inserted is :-5078.279785

Comment: I hope you haven't forgot brackets, i.e. `(f-'0')*100` instead of `f-'0'*100`? :)

Comment: Nevermind, i just made it work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Each char you are getting has an ASCII value. For example if your char is "1" then it's numerical value is 49. Maybe you want to look up the function scanf. It is similar to printf but it is for input.